# Computer Organization and Assembly Language Programming

Tags: computer-architecture, mips

Why do we need to learn MIPS Assembly language before learning computer organization? What are the implications of learning it first?

As a computer scientist, why do we need to learn this one and where will these topics will become handy?

with references:

-Computer Organization and Design by Patterson and Hennessy

-Introduction to Digital Logic Design by John Hayes

Comment: I'd say one can be a CScientist without knowing MIPS. However, in a CS program one does not learn MIPS for the sake of MIPS, but for understanding the ideas behind machine code and assembly, as general concepts. Without that, it is impossible to design a CPU, whose primary task is to execute machine code. I'd regard learning assembly as learning the definition of a problem to solve in hardware.

Answer (score 1):

Learning assembly language will be helpful for you in understanding computer architecture, because the CPU is designed to run the instructions that are part of its assembly language.  So, to understand what the CPU is doing and why it was designed that way, you need to know what operations it is designed to support.